# Ratchet.js and window.history.back();

Tags: javascript, jquery, ratchet-2

I have an **init** function with all my jQuery staff that I execute on document ready and with a **push** event listener:

```
function init() {
    //all my jquery staff
}
window.addEventListener('push', init);
$(document).ready(function() {
    init();
});
```

On a page loaded via **push** I have a back link on the header. Notice the **back** class.

```
<header class="bar bar-nav">
    <a class="icon icon-left-nav pull-left back" data-transition="slide-out"></a>
    <h1 class="title">My Title</h1>
</header>
```

To go back I use

```
$('.back').click(function (event) {
    window.history.back();
    return false;
});
```

And it works great. However, **after going back, none of my other jquery staff works.**

I have try onpopstatechange but some of my jquery executes more than once

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  init();
}
```

**Any ideas on how to implement the back button on ratchet.js?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
PUSH({ url: href,  transition: "slide-out" })
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this is a good solution.